# Renaming file based on the content of two values from the first line

Tags: batch-file

I have files that its first line would look like this:

VND|OVERSTOCKL|OSH|004010

It is a pipe delimiter and only the first three characters remain the same among all files.
I need a batch file that reads this first line and if, and only if it finds "OVERSTOCKL", it will rename the file from ####.### to OVERSTOCKL856.DAT

The 856 is based on OSH at the third place from the fist line.

If OIN, then it should be OVERSTOCKL810.DAT

If OIB, then it should be OVERSTOCKL846.DAT

If OPR, then it should be OVERSTOCKL855.DAT

If OVERSTOCKL is not found, it should do nothing to the file name.

Can this be done?

Thanks.

Comment: Yes, it can be done. But what if two files in the same folder have OVERSTOCK and OSH in the first line? Only one file can have the specified name. And you haven't asked a satisfactory programming question.

Comment: It won't! But good point. You made me think; there could be others (larger) files with multiple "VND|OVERSTOCKL|OSH|004010" lines and VND lines with other names after the "VND|other_names|OSH|004030". If this is the case, I am in trouble. The batch should then extract every singles line, including the VND all the the last one before the next VND and save it onto another file giving the name already described.

Answer (score 0):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir\t w o"
FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN (
 'dir /b /a-d "%sourcedir%\*" '
 ) DO (
 SET "processed="
 SET "name="
 FOR /f "usebackqtokens=1-4delims=|" %%t IN ("%sourcedir%\%%a") DO (
 IF NOT DEFINED processed IF "%%u"=="OVERSTOCKL" (
  IF "%%v"=="OIN" SET "name=810"
  IF "%%v"=="OIB" SET "name=846"
  IF "%%v"=="OPR" SET "name=855"
  IF "%%v"=="OSH" SET "name=856"
 )
 SET "processed=Y"
 )
 IF DEFINED name CALL :CHANGE "%%a"
)

GOTO :EOF

:CHANGE
IF "%~1"=="OVERSTOCKL%name%.dat" GOTO :eof
IF EXIST "%sourcedir%\OVERSTOCKL%name%.dat" (
 ECHO OVERSTOCKL%name%.dat already exists naming "%~1"
 GOTO :eof
)
ECHO(REN "%sourcedir%\%~1" "OVERSTOCKL%name%.dat"

GOTO :eof
```

You would need to change the setting of `sourcedir` to suit your circumstances.

The required REN commands are merely `ECHO`ed for testing purposes. **After you've verified that the commands are correct**, change `ECHO(REN` to `REN` to actually rename the files.

Perform a directory scan of the source directory, in `/b` basic mode `/a-d` without directories and assign each filename found to `%%a`.

For each filename in `%%a`, set `name` and `processed` to *nothing* and read a line from the file. If the second token is as specified then set `name` to the potential new name from the third token.

Setting `processed` to any value ensures that only the very first line is read.

If `name` is set, renaming is required and executed by the subroutine `:change`.

If the filename being processed has already been examined, don't bother trying to rename. If the destination name exists already, produce an error line and if not, do the rename.

Answer (score 0):

This solution assumes that the "VND|OVERSTOCKL|" string can appear at first line only; if this is not true, a small modification is required.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem Define the equivalence numbers
set "number[OSH]=856"
set "number[OIN]=810"
set "number[OIB]=846"
set "number[OPR]=855"

rem Process files that have "VND|OVERSTOCKL|" string at beginning of line only
cd "D:\Folder"
for /F "tokens=1,3,4 delims=:|" %%a in ('findstr /B "VND|OVERSTOCKL|" *.*') do (

   rem FINDSTR output have this format: "FILENAME.EXT:VND|OVERSTOCKL|OSH|004010"

   rem Do the required rename
   ECHO ren "%%a" "%%b!number[%%c]!.DAT"

)
```

The `ren` command is just echoed to the screen. If the output is correct, remove the `ECHO` part in order to execute the rename.